# Is it okay to strike off expenses in bank statement?

Tags: salary, recruitment, india

My first employer was a startup and not very keen on documentation. And so I did not receive any salary receipts. My new employer is demanding the salary receipts from the previous employer and said I can show my bank statement if I don't have those.
As I understand, my financial transactions are not concern of the new employer. In that situation, can I strike off (cover with ink) other transactions leaving the salary credit? Is that an accepted practice?

Comment: Asking if something is an accepted practice requires us to know where you are located.

Comment: Where are you located that your future employer needs to see your salary receipts? In some places it's actually illegal to ask for that information.

Comment: Many things here seems strange to me because i'm based in Latin America and we have many differences with NA, EU and Asia, but this seems really odd, why does your new employer want a salary receipt?

Comment: I'm from India and it's norm here for employers to seek information about past salary so that they can add 30-50% over the previous salary instead of paying what they intended to. There is no way around it. You don't show it, you don't get the job. No law is stopping them to not seek such sensitive information either. And so they need the salary sheet to see the candidate is saying truth about his past salary or not. That is my understanding though. I really don't know for sure why they need it.

Comment: @DavidK I wish it was so here. I have faced a lot of discrimination just because my previous employer underpaid me. I discussed that here sometimes ago.

Comment: Have you thought about asking your bank to provide a statement of the last 3 months payments from the previous employer - no extra info like that...

Comment: Have you asked the prospective employer if that would be suitable?

Comment: @dwizum ask them what? I don't understand your question. The employer will need my private transaction or not is not the employer's to decide. I'm simply asking if it legal to do because bank statement is an official document.

Comment: @SolarMike actually no. And I'm sure I will be disappointed. I will ask and report then.

Comment: In Canada, we often strike our personal bank transactions before submitting an expense to an employer. May be you could strike the personal transactions and see how the new employer react?

Comment: What region of the world.  I would not supply a bank statement, it's not as an official, as you might think.  Something like your W2 from your last employer would give them the information they are asking for.  Legal questions are out of scope contact a lawyer in your region in order to determine if the employer is allowed to ask for this information.

Comment: If you use online banking, most systems i have seen have a filter function where you can select e.g. only income and from a specific source. Then print only those, so no need to strike something off.

Comment: "I'm from India". I have a colleague who is from India, and another one from New Zealand. Their accepted practices are UK accepted practices because they both work in the UK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should be ok to strike off any visibility of financial information that isn't related to your previous income (if it's legal for your employer to ask).

Your new employer only needs to see the amount of salary paid and verify the payer reference.  If they need to see anything more than that, then you'd really have to question that request.